# Read date format DD/MM/YYYY using pandas.read_json

Tags: python, pandas, date

I have a file date.json with date format DD/MM/YYYY

```
{
    "18/3/2020": 0,
    "19/3/2020": 3,
    "20/3/2020": 5,
    "21/3/2020": 1,
    "22/3/2020": 6,
    "23/3/2020": 3,
    ...
    "11/1/2022": 558,
    "12/1/2022": 0
}
```

I use the following code to read the json file

```
series = pd.read_json("date.json", typ="series")
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':series.index, column:series.values}).set_index("date")
```

But when I tried to print the date column, the date data is saved as YYYY-MM-DD and misunderstands that January 12, 2022 is December 1, 2022 as follow

```
date                                                                 
2020-03-18                         
2020-03-19                        
2020-03-20                            
2020-03-21                           
2020-03-22                          
...                           
2022-08-01                           
2022-09-01                       
2022-10-01                         
2022-11-01                         
2022-12-01
```

What can I read the json data in the right date format without change the data file?

Comment: What's wrong with your code?

Comment: I read a json file into dataframe by pd.read_json but it misunderstood that January 12, 2022 (12/1/2022) is December 1, 2022 (2022-12-01)

Comment: In your expected output, it should be 2022-12-01 (already the case, 1st december 2022) or 2022-01-12 (12th january 2022)

Comment: It should be 2022-01-12

Comment: OK. but it's not possible with your data... because "18/3/2020" can't be "2020-18-3"

Comment: Because my date data is formatted as day/month/year but it seems that the code can be interpreted in terms of day/month/year (March 18, 2020) or month/day/year (January 12, 2022) ).

Comment: it's reading it correcty just only pandas shows it by default as year-month-date

Comment: The real bug is in the producer of that file. That's what needs to be fixed. That JSON file contains raw text, not dates. [The standard way to serialize dates in JSON](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7493#section-4.3) is the ISO8601 format (YYYY-MM-DD). Otherwise there's *no* way to know what the actual date is, causing the problem you just encountered.

Comment: In case the producer of those strings (not dates) complains, point them to [RFC 7493](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7493#section-4.3) `It is RECOMMENDED that all such data items be expressed as string values in ISO 8601 format`

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by specifying the date format in pandas.
Remember pandas by default will show dates as year-month-date.

```
df.index=pd.to_datetime(df.index,format='%d/%m/%Y')

#output:
            value
2020-03-18      0
2020-03-19      3
2020-03-20      5
2020-03-21      1
2020-03-22      6
2020-03-23      3
2022-01-11    558
2022-01-12      0
```

If you want to verify that's reading correctly the month and the day you can create columns with day and month number. Notice it's reading the last row as January 12

```
df.index=pd.to_datetime(df.index,format='%d/%m/%Y')
df['dates_str']=df.index.map(lambda x: x.strftime('%b %d %Y'))
df['day']=df.index.day
df['month']=df.index.month
df['year']=df.index.year

#output
            value    dates_str  day  month  year
2020-03-18      0  Mar 18 2020   18      3  2020
2020-03-19      3  Mar 19 2020   19      3  2020
2020-03-20      5  Mar 20 2020   20      3  2020
2020-03-21      1  Mar 21 2020   21      3  2020
2020-03-22      6  Mar 22 2020   22      3  2020
2020-03-23      3  Mar 23 2020   23      3  2020
2022-01-11    558  Jan 11 2022   11      1  2022
2022-01-12      0  Jan 12 2022   12      1  2022
```